# How to call something that can be both a user and a usergroup?

Tags: object-oriented, naming, abstraction

My idea is, to create an abstract class / interface which can be extended into a user, and into a usergroup.

There actually is a good reason for there being this interface connecting the groups with the users as the only differences between a user and a group is that you can login as a user and you can't as a group, and that a group can contain multiple users or groups. Permissions and stuff are handled without taking notice of it being a user or a group.

Comment: What language?  The best answer is different in Python, Java and C++.

Comment: C++ - How is language relevant though?

Comment: If I wanted two different kinds of objects to be callable from the same function, in C++ I'd usually create an abstract class, in Java I'd create an interface, and in Python just make sure that the correct methods exist in both classes.

Comment: Yeah I have the abstract class made, but what should I name it? :S

Comment: `PermissionEntity` would work for me for the abstract concept.  But as they say, there are only two hard problems in computer science: naming, cache invalidation and off by one errors.

Comment: In Windows NT there is also `Trustee`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In computer security, users and groups are referred to as [Principals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780957%28WS.10%29.aspx).

> Security principals include the following:
>
> - Any entity that can be authenticated by the system, such as a user    account, a computer account, or a thread or process that runs in the
>     security context of a user or computer account.
> - Security groups of these accounts.

Comment: You need to put [square brackets] around the item to be linked as well as a bracketed number [n]: link in order for the link to integrate. I've also taken the liberty of placing an excerpt in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest answer is to use composition.

Have a class for the group.  Have a method on a user that gives the one element group that is the user.  Allow one group to be included in another one.  Inclusion is a transitive relation, implemented through recursion, that you can speed up at run-time by caching the fact that group X is or is not included in group Y.  Add the user to a group by including the user's group in the other group.

And now you never need to have a method that can accept either a user or a group.  Any given method either accepts a user and does things that a group cannot do, or accepts the group that you can get from the user.

Answer (score -2):

"EndUser" may be? I thought it can be a name for a group of people related to both the group or single user, they all "use in the end"